# Why is this for loop throwing an IndexOutOfBoundsException?

Tags: java

Please help, i am getting index out of bound exception in following code

```
public static void main (String[] args){

    String st = "harpreet"; 

    for(int i=1; i<=st.length(); i++){

        System.out.print(st.charAt(i));

    }

}
```

Comment: Hint: array indices start from zero, not one.

Comment: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 8
 at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)

Comment: If it was me asking this, people here on SO would have already down voted my question of -10 least.

Answer (score 2):

Array offsets begin at 0, not 1.  If you start at 1 you miss offset 0.  Also, make the compare < st.length(), or else you go out of bounds

```
for(int i=0; i< st.length(); i++){
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to read.

```
for(int i=0; i< st.length(); i++){
```

Index Out of Bound means that you are trying to reference an i that does not exist in your array range. You are falling off of your array because arrays are 0 to n-1 not 1 to n.

Answer (score 0):

Array index starts with 0 but you calculate the length of the string start with 1 like "harpreet" length is 8 but "h" letter index is 0.

IndexOutOfBoundException is a runtime Exception and it occurs when you are trying to reach the array which doesn't exist.

your code should be -

```
for(int i=0; i< st.length(); i++)
```